# Empty white space at the bottom of my react app

Tags: html, css

Hello I have a problem with the white space at bottom of my website. I checked stackoverflow and tricks like `body { padding: 20px } or body { border: 1px solid black}` does not work.

Background css (it covers whole page / it should cover whole page but there is a white space at bottom) I also checked if any component in my website has padding but only buttons has paddings and it did not solve problem.

```
.Background {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: rgb(248, 245, 245);
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('../../../images/Storm.jpg');
    object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: fill;
}



@media  screen and  (max-width: 35em)  { 
    .Background {
      height: auto;
        
    }
}

@media  screen and  (max-width: 65em)  { 
    .Background {
       height: auto;
        
    }
}
```

index.css

```
 html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*, 
*::after
*::before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  
}

@media  screen and  (max-width: 35em)  { 
  body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
      
  }
}

@media  screen and  (max-width: 62.5em)  { 
  body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
      
  }
}

#root {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  
  
}



code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, 'Courier New',
    monospace;
}
```

Comment: can you share your code in online editors or put a snippet of your code...

Comment: Are you using a framework like Material UI?

Comment: In my case, I was using animate.css animation on my footer (slide up), removing the animation from footer fixed it. Maybe will be helpful to someone.

Comment: I'm facing similar problems. I can't add 100vh as it is messing up with the vertical responsive behavior and I have already 100% to html and body set.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your viewport as the following

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no, viewport-fit=cover">
```

Answer (score 1):

a simple fix would be to add:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I modified and it does not work :(

Answer (score 0):

you should add this code:

```
html, body {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

or you can also do this:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The best fix will be:**

```
html, body {
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why it worked but i added wrapper to the Background with height: 10% and white space disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Must be a component in your screen with bottom padding and limited by the top, so the web app resizes his heigth adding that white space in order to achieve the bottom padding :).